# How to build an array from a list? (without ArrayList)

Tags: java, arrays, list, file

I'm trying to build an array from a file that lists 43 countries along with 4 other specific information fields about them on their respective lines. I got the code I have to read the code (verified with echo print) but I'm not sure how to process the rest of the code so I can get some results in terms of output.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

        String inputString = null; 
        String cName;
        String cCapital;
        String regionNum;
        int capitalPop;
        int region;

        File f = new File("Countries.txt"); 
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 


        while (inputString != null)
        { 
            cName = inputString.substring(0, 15).trim();
            cCapital = inputString.substring(15, 30); 
            capitalPop = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(55, 60));

            inputString = br.readLine(); 

        }

        br.close(); 
        fr.close(); 
}
```

The three lines in the while loop have sample values for trimming from the file's lines. I think my main problem is that I'm conceptually confused. Any input is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is this, by any chance, for a Computer Science class?

Comment: I don't see a list here.

Comment: Yup double checked.. No List found.

Comment: not related to question but you need to put a line `inputString = br.readLine();` before the while loop `while (inputString != null)`.

Comment: Your question could be reworded, as you don't start with what we'd consider an actual "list", but merely a `String` that has its items separated by space characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of us see a `List` in your code, but this is how it should be done:

You need to create an ArrayList and then add an object of each individual country to it. You could directly use an array instead if the number of countries is always fixed at 43.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

        String inputString = null; 
        String cName;
        String cCapital;
        String regionNum;
        int capitalPop;
        int region;

        File f = new File("Countries.txt"); 
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        inputString = br.readLine();    
        while (inputString != null)
        { 
            cName = inputString.substring(0, 15).trim();
            cCapital = inputString.substring(15, 30); 
            capitalPop = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(55, 60));
            Country country = new Country();
            country.setCName(cName);
            // set other members
            countries.add(country); // This is your list of countries
            inputString = br.readLine();    
        }
        Country[] countryArray = new Country[countries.size()];
        countries.toArray(countryArray);
        // voila.. the country array.
        br.close(); 
        fr.close(); 
}


public class Country {

 private String cName;
 private String cCapital;
 //.. other fields;


 public String getCName(){ return this.cName;}
 public void setCName(String cName) {this.cName = cName;}
 // create other setters / getters for each of the member variables.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `List` Object in your code... But to take a List and put it in an array call the  `toArray()` method see the api docs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

I would read about CSV files (comma-separated values, or comma-delimited values) and common ways to read from them.  Classes such as a Scanner can delimit each read line by a specific value, so you can rely on that delimiter instead of explicitly stating the length of characters.  Depending on how the text is organized in the file, this may be more efficient and sensible.  Also, your delimiter can be any string, most commonly ",".

Also, I would define a class which holds the values you need to store and create an array of that type which holds your data.  Then, you can read back through that array later and call a toString() method you've defined for it to print the stored values.